# Приложение не выводится в окно эмулятора Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android

Здравствуйте!

Приложение Android Studio успешно компилируется, загружается в память, но не выводится в окно эмулятора среды Android Studio. Подскажите, почему.

Выкладываю файл AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ru.mbn.hellokitty" >

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: А ошибки как-нибудь есть? В логах что пишется?

Answer (score 1):

А может, не задан класс по умолчанию? 
Посмотрите в

```
Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Android Application -> НАЗВАНИЕ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ -> Activity -> Launch [ru.mbn.hellokitty.ТРЕБУЕМЫЙ_КЛАСС] <- введите сюда нужный класс
```